# Proof that type does not have decidable equality in Agda

Tags: homotopy-type-theory, agda, cubical-type-theory

Can one create such function in Agda ?

```
ℕ→ℕ-undecidable : ¬ ( (f g :  ℕ → ℕ ) → Dec (f ≡ g)) 
ℕ→ℕ-undecidable = ?
```

I am particularly interested in proof using cubical Agda.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ℕ→ℕ-undecidable` is not provable in Agda. If we postulate the law of excluded middle (LEM), it follows that equality on every set is decidable, contradicting `ℕ→ℕ-undecidable`. Since Agda is consistent with LEM, it follows that `ℕ→ℕ-undecidable` is not provable in base Agda. This holds the same for cubical and vanilla Agda.

Comment: What about coq? Is it possible to prove it there?

Comment: @srghma no, the same thing holds for Coq. Consistency with LEM (classical logic) is a common expected feature in proof assistants.